# How to create a overlay that persists across screens in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm looking to build something similar to the way Spotify (or other music players) work, where there is a footer element that allows you to control the currently playing music that persists regardless of how you navigate through the app. See the bottom of this image as an example.

[See the bottom here with the playing music](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPLh0.png)

Requirements for this are that the different screens must be able to communicate with that component so users can choose music from any screen. The component must persist across screens so that the currently playing music will be controllable even as you use the app.

I'm building in react-native and currently using react-navigation as my navigation solution, in case that makes a difference.

Comment: Create a root component with the player and add the rest of your app as a child of the root component.